# Depletion region in metals

Tags: diodes, depletion-region

Can we create a depletion region  (just like in diodes) between two dissimilar metals?What would be the use of that?

Comment: Metals aren't semiconductors. What would keep the charges apart?

Comment: You can create a depletion region between a metal and a semiconductor. That's what a schottky diode. I don't think you can do it with metals because you can't dope them.

Comment: If the two metals have different number of electrons / volume then electrons would diffuse from one metal to another.

Comment: I know schottky diodes.

Comment: What do you mean cant dope them?

Comment: @Altair See this image [Metals, semi-metals, semiconductors, etc](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Band_filling_diagram.svg/300px-Band_filling_diagram.svg.png) taken from this Wiki site [Electronic band structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure). See if that helps you see the problem better.

Comment: Nah yes you are right:) I forgot completely the band gaps!

Comment: But it could have very low forward voltage.

Comment: Metal does have the lowest forward voltage. So low that it's zero volts, and conducts both ways!

Comment: Hmmm.The band gap of metal in a dchottky diode is big enough.How do you explain that?

Comment: A schottky doesn't have two metals. It has one metal and one semiconductor.

Comment: So the band gap of the metal is changed somehow magically?

Comment: @Altair No, the bandgap of the semiconductor is enough. The metal still has no bandgap.

Comment: @Toor, in the schottky diode, the depletion region forms in the semiconductor, not in the metal.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yeah, and if you have two metals you have no semiconductor so no depletion region.

Comment: OP, You can form a [thermocouple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple) at the junction of two metals.